# Getting webpage source code without freezing UI

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, swingworker

I am trying to get the source code of a webpage but when I do that, the UI freezes. I even used SwingWorker but it didn't work. Here is a SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
public class SSCCE extends JPanel {

    public SSCCE() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JButton action = new JButton("Action");
        action.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingWorker<String, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<String, Void>(){
                    protected String doInBackground() {
                        try {
                            URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
                            InputStream is = url.openStream();
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            String line;
                            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line);
                            }
                            if (is != null) is.close();
                            String source = sb.toString();
                            return source;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                };
                worker.execute();
                try {
                    System.out.println(worker.get());
                } catch (HeadlessException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        add(action);

        JButton nothing = new JButton("Nothing");
        add(nothing);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SSCCE();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to get the source code or a way to get it where the UI doesn't freeze? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that even though you're using a `SwingWorker`, you immediately turn around and tell the UI to wait for it (`worker.get()`). Instead, your worker should use a *callback*--when its work is done, it should invoke some action, probably on the event thread, that tells the UI to do the next thing.

Comment: Two recommendations, either override the `done` method or add a `PropertyChangeListener` to the worker and monitor for the `done` state...+1

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would I do that in a method? I am returning the source code from a method.

Comment: @usama8800 Not really, you creating anonymous class within the `actionPerformed` method.  Override the `done` method and call another method with the result of the `doInBackground`.  When `done` is called, you can call `get`, which will return the value returned from `doInBackground`, this guarantees two things, one, it won't block and two, `done` is called from within the context of the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer This is an SSCCE. In the original program, I'm using a method.

Comment: @usama8800 Then your SSCCE should reflect more what you are doing, otherwise we have no hope...The problem you might have to overcome is the fact that the method you are calling either needs to be none-blocking or called from the context of the `SwingWorker`...